# Why should I use a different number of escape characters in different situations?

Tags: java, regex

With regular expressions in Java, why I should write `"\n"` to define a new line character and `"\\s"` to define whitespace character?

Why does the quantity of backslashes differs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java does its own string parsing, converting it from your code to an internal string in memory and *before* it sends the string to the regex parser.

Java converts the 2 characters `\n` to a linefeed (ASCII code `0x0A`) and the first 2 (!) characters in `\\s` to a single backslash: `\s`. Now *this* string is sent to the regex parser, and since regular expressions recognize their *own* special escaped characters, it treats the `\s` as "any whitespace".

At this point, the code `\n` is already stored as a single character "linefeed", and the regular expression does not process it again.

Since regular expressions *also* recognize the set `\n` as "a linefeed", you can also use `\\n` in your Java string -- Java converts the escaped `\\` to a single `\`, and the regular expression module then finds `\n`, which (again) gets translated into a linefeed.

Answer (score 3):

A Java string has a certain set of allowed [escape sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), of which "\n" is one, but "\s" is not. A string doesn't understand the regexp shorthand for whitespace. You're probably passing a Java string to the `RegExp` constructor, so in order to pass "\s" as a string, you have to escape the "\" by doubling it.

Answer (score 2):

`\` is special character in many languages (in Java it is special in `String` or `char`) or tools like regex.

In `String` or `char` it is used to create other special characters which you normally couldn't write. By using `\x` where `x` is representation of that special character you are able to create

- `\t` tab
- `\b` backspace
- `\n` newline
- `\r` carriage return
- `\f` formfeed

or to escape other special characters

- `\'` single quote (`'` is special in `char` because it represents where char starts and ends, so to actually write `'` character you need to escape it and write it as

  ```
  here we start creating character
  |  here we end creating character 
  ↓  ↓
  '\''
   ↑↑
   here we created literal of '
  ```
- `\"` double quote - similarly to `\'` in `char`, in String `"` represents where it starts and ends, so to put `"` literal into string (to actually be able to write it) you need to escape it

  ```
  here we start creating String
  |  here we end creating String 
  ↓  ↓
  "\""
   ↑↑
   here we created literal of "
  ```
- `\\` backslash - since `\` is special character used to create others special character there has to be a way to un-special it so we could actually print `\` as simple literal.

  Problem: how to write string representing `day\night`? If you write it such string in a way `"day\night" it will be interpreted as`day[newline]ight`.

  So in many languages to represent `\` literal another `\` is added before it to escape it. So String which represent `day\night` needs to be written as `"day\\night"` (now `\` in `\n` is escaped so it no longer represents `\n` - newline - but concatenation of `\` and `n` characters)

---

In case of regex to represent character class which will accept any whitespace you need to actually pass `\s`.
But string which will represent `\s` needs to be written as `"\\s"` because as mentioned earlier in String `\` is special and needs escaping.
If you would write `\s` as `"\s"` you would get