# How to escape + character in java?

Tags: java, string, escaping

How to escape + character while using split function call in java?

split declaration

```
String[] split(String regularExpression)
```

thats what i did

```
services.split("+"); //says dongling metacharacter

services.split("\+"); //illegal escape character in string literal
```

But it allows to do something like this

```
String regExpr="+";
```

Comment: @kocko thanks a lot .... **but why i must \\ + character?** why not \?

Comment: because `+` is a regex special characters and `split` accepts regex

Comment: @JordiCastilla but as  i know split accepts String. Is there any special type of string for split? IDE notifies me these errors . i did't compile that.

Comment: Java tries to make a special character out of \+ like \n and \t, but you don't want Java to do this. You want \ and + as two characters. So you have to escape the \, then \\ becomes \ but it will not be combined with +.

Comment: @kocko post your comment as answer

Comment: Why do I need two slashes in Java Regex to find a `+` symbol? Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145793/why-do-i-need-two-slashes-in-java-regex-to-find-a-symobl

Comment: @Xean thanks buddy thats the perfect one .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `+` is a regex meta-character (denoting an occurrence of 1 or more times), you will have to escape it with `\` (which also has to be escaped because it's a meta-character that's being used when describing the tab character, the new line character(s) `\r\n` and others), so you have to do:

```
services.split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 2):

Java and Regex both have special escape sequences, and both of them begin with `\`.

Your issue lies in writing a string literal in Java. Java's escape sequences are resolved at compile time, long before the string is passed into your Regex engine for parsing.

The sequence `"\+"` would throw an error as this is not a valid Java string.

If you want to pass `\+` into your Regex engine you have to explicitly let Java know you want to pass in a backslash character using `"\\+"`.

All valid Java escape sequences are as follows:

```
\t  Insert a tab in the text at this point.
\b  Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r  Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
\f  Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
\'  Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
\"  Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
\\  Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.
```

Answer (score 1):

should be like this :

```
services.split("\\+");
```